# C# Producer/Consumer queue with delays

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

The problem is the classic N producers (with N possibly large) and X consumers with limited resources (X is currently 4). The producers messages come in (say via MQTT) and get queued to be processed by consumers on a FIFO basis. The important part of the processing is that each consumer may need to send back to the producers one or more "replies" and such replies should be at least some time apart (the exact delay is not important). The classic solution where one starts X tasks that wait on the message queue, process and loop is easy to implement using, for example, `System.Threading.Channels`:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && await queue.Reader.WaitToReadAsync()) {
    while (queue.Reader.TryRead(out IncomingMessage item)) {
        // Do some processing.
        SendResponse(1);
        // Do some more processing.
        if (needsToSend2Response) {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            SendResponse(2);
        }
    }
}
```

This works and works well *except* that if a task needs to delay it can't process any more messages and that's obviously bad.

Possible solutions I thought of:

1. Use an outbound queue that process the messages and makes sure there is at least a minimum delay between messages sent to the same producer.
2. Don't use a queue. Just start a new Task every time a new message comes in and arbitrate the limited resources using a semaphore: it works but I don't see how to guarantee the FIFO requirement (some times messages from the same producer are processed in the wrong order).

Any other ideas?

Comment: So there's a requirement that two messages cannot be processed for the same producer at the same time even if other consumers are otherwise idle?

Comment: Sounds like you need to put the delayed response onto another queue, which you can pull off using another loop. I agree though that using a `Task` for each individual message makes more sense.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is a "relaxed" requirements: it is important to process the messages *mostly* in the right order. The rate of messages is 1 every few seconds and if I can guarantee to process the message in less than 1 second everything works even without an explicit control on ordering.

Comment: My immediate instinct is to put a message back into the same queue to say "send response 2 not earlier than X" and if it cycles a few times (because X hasn't been reached so you requeue), that just means the queues are otherwise empty. But it's tricky to tell whether that would fit.

Comment: Sounds like you would be best served with an outgoing queue (or one per producer). As you noted, the `SemaphoreSlim` doesn't guarantee FIFO behavior and there's no way to force that.

Comment: @StephenCleary yes, I think the outgoing queue is the best solution. What I'd really like to have (because it would make the code I have to write straightforward) is a queue of tasks and a custom thread pool that parks "not ready" tasks (the ones that call Delay()) back on the queue and guarantees FIFO processing of the ready tasks. Unfortunately I haven't found nothing like that, and I don't think I'll try to write it myself, given that this is production code.

Comment: @fog all that is already implemented by .NET. A Channel already guarantees both write and read order. Writing to the output queue doesn't have to be the job of the first consumer method. You can have another method that "produces" responses. That method can easily contain a delay. Essentially, you create another one-way "channel" where old "consumer" is now the "producer".